Is xr-hyper compatible with amsart?
I'm having trouble using xr-hyper (for cross-referencing between files) with the class amsart.
The following code gives me an error when trying to compile both .tex files (see below); whichever file I compile first goes through, but then the second file fails to compile. It works as expected if I replace \usepackage{amsart} with \usepackage{article}.
The files do compile (with correct references displayed) if I write \usepackage{xr} instead of \usepackage{xr-hyper}, but in that case the cross-file hyperlinks seem misdirected (for both the article class and amsart class).
Any suggestions?

File one, called my_part_I.tex

\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\externaldocument{my_part_II}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction for Part I}
\label{sec:part_I}

See \ref{sec:part_I} or \ref{sec:part_II}.

\end{document}



File two, called my_part_II.tex

\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\externaldocument{my_part_I}

\begin{document}

\addtocounter{section}{1}
\section{Introduction for Part II}
\label{sec:part_II}

See \ref{sec:part_I} or \ref{sec:part_II}.

\end{document}



Edit: On request, here's some more info about the errors.
I must confess I am no LaTeX expert, so I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right errors.
--
My TeXworks console gives me
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.11 \section{Introduction for Part II}

when I try to compile my_part_II.tex
--
When trying the same thing on Overleaf (which requires some workaround for xr-hyper, but which I use regularly with the article class), the files compile but with several warnings (and the cross-file references display as "??" in my_part_II.pdf). Upon compiling my_part_I.tex, I get
Label `tocindent-1' multiply defined.
Label `tocindent0' multiply defined.
Label `tocindent1' multiply defined.
Label `tocindent2' multiply defined.
Label `tocindent3' multiply defined.

If I then compile my_part_II.tex, I get
Reference `sec:part_I' on page 1 undefined on input line 50.


Welcome to tex.sx.

Please cite the errors you get.

The problem is that amsart uses the label-ref system to store toc indent values. While this doesn't error with xr (yet, with the next latex release this changes) you still get the wrong value and duplicated labels. Load the external file with a prefix: \externaldocument[A-]{my_part_I}.

If you compile one of your files (without xr-hyper) and look into the aux-file you will see label definitions like this:
\newlabel{tocindent-1}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent0}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent1}{17.77782pt}
\newlabel{tocindent2}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent3}{0pt}

amsart uses this to store indentation values for the next run.
These \newlabel define  commands \r@tocindent0 etc. When you load an external document, amsart sees either only the \newlabel's from the external document (which has a wrong value and a wrong format as xr-hyper has added a file info) and errors, or it sees the \newlabel's from both aux-files and complains about multiplied labels.
Imho the only way around the problem is to use a prefix to ensure that the names do not overlap: \externaldocument[A-]{my_part_II}.
As a sidenote: While it doesn't currently error with xr the outcome is wrong nevertheless. Also with the next LaTeX xr and xr-hyper will be merged and do the same.

I followed your suggestion to make it work - thanks for sharing your expertise!

In case you don't want to use a prefix with externaldocument, another workaround is to downgrade to TeX Live 2023.

A reason as to why TexLive 2023 is a better choice would be helpful to this answer.

It does not produce this error. I have used it all the time in the manner OP describes in the question, without issue. I don’t understand the technical reason. I stumbled upon the question after upgrading and noticing some of my compilations failed.
